# Aspose.Word wrong hyphenation when converting to PDF

Tags: pdf, aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

In Microsoft Word, when you have hyphenation, the target word is not allowed to be sent to the new page.
Your entire line goes on the new page.

When I convert such docx file to PDF using Aspose.Words, the result PDF does not follow this rule, hence I end up with different page layouts, which I do not want.

What I tried:

- using custom hyphenation dictionaries, which I load into Aspose.Words (German language)
- altering the docx somehow with `HyphenationOptions` field (they do not work when converting to fixed page format)
- altering the page margins -> this is not a solution, because I want 1:1 conversion
- Using different compatibility modes -> I left the `Aspose.Words.Settings.MsWordVersion.Word2019`
- Using Apose.Pdf somehow -> problems is that I do not build the PDF myself, hence I am limited on how to display it
- Using `Aspose.Words.Saving.PdfSaveOptions` and various settings -> no success

Version of Aspose.Words: 20.8.0 (latest version)

**PDF:**

---

some text here

überra-

*page 1*

---

---

schung

*page 2*

---

**WORD:**

---

some text here

*page 1*

---

---

Überraschung

*page 2*

---

Comment: *"hence I end up with different page layouts, which I do not want"* - that's something that can always happen when outputting word processor files to different targets; sometimes printing to a different printer from Word itself causes similar differences. Word processor formats in contrast to PDF simply aren't meant to produce identical outputs.

Comment: @antanta It is difficult to say what the problem is without your input document. I would suggest you to report this problem in Aspose.Words support forum and attach your input, output and desired output documents there. https://forum.aspose.com/c/words